# Stop The Global Warming

Tags: grammar, meaning

I was going to register a domain like 'StopGlobalWarming.com', but it had registered already. Then I changed it to 'StopTheGlobalWarming.com'. Are there any problems with it? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domain names are advertising, not grammar.  Anything that gets traffic is good.

In normal speech you don't use "the".  This is because "warming" is used as the participle/gerund of the verb "warm" and not an independent noun.  This may change. There is a natural grammar change from gerunds to nouns, and you can have "Stop the warming of the Earth!"

But that doesn't matter.  For a domain name, "Stoptheglobalwarming" is not good because it is too long, and people will forget to put in "the" and end up at the domain squatter that owns "stopglobalwarming".